# Cannot Execute Stored Procedure using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I use sybase database and am trying to update some values into the database.

While trying to run this it throws an exception as :
com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybSQLException: The identifier that starts with 'WeeklyStudentEventClassArchiv' is too long. Maximum length is 30.

This table is in another database and thus i have to use the database name along with the table name as dhown below:
StudActive..WeeklyStudentEventClassArchiv which apparently exceeds 30 characters.

I have to use the databasename..tablename in the stored procudure but its throwing an exception.

This happens even if i physically embed the sql in the java code.

How can this be solved.

```
The Stored Procedue is as shown:
create proc dbo.sp_getStudentList(
@stDate int,
@endDate int
)
as
begin
set nocount on

      select distinct studCode
      StudActive..WeeklyStudentEventClassArchive      
      where studCode > 0
      and courseStartDate between @stDate and @endDate 



end
```

Comment: Can you execute the stored procedure directly?

Answer (score 0):

> StudActive..WeeklyStudentEventClassArchiv which apparently exceeds 30
>   characters.

Yes - I count 41.

Rename the table and/or the stored proc and you should be fine.  It wounds like a limitation of either the JDBC driver or the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I cannot rename the table .Is there any other way.

Comment: No other way that I know of.  You can rename the stored proc, right?

Comment: Renaming the stored procedure is not an issue.But how will it solve the problem.The problem lies in the table used inside the stored procedure right.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I mis-read what the cited string meant.  You have your answer from the JDBC driver: It won't accept more than 30 chars.  You'll either rename the table or not call it through Java.  Your choice.

Comment: By which way can i call if not by java.

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC driver is out of date.  Updating to a later version might help solve your problem.

First [download](http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/softwaredeveloperkit/jconnect) a more recent jConnect driver from the Sybase website.  Then update your code to use the new driver package.  You will also need to change your code, as the package name of the driver changes for each new version of the specification.  (The current package is com.sybase.jdbcx...)

Take a look at the [programmers reference](http://www.scribd.com/normandben/d/52826693-Programmers-reference-Jconnect-7-0) for more information.